# How can I access a file or directory on Chrome OS?

Tags: python, file, google-chrome, directory, zip

I am new to machine learning, and have taken a few courses regarding the use of TensorFlow. However, these courses used pre-loaded datasets, and, while looking to create an image classifier on my own, I realized I did not know how to load a dataset from my files. I am using a school-issued Chromebook from 2015.

[image: My image directory, with the path I am looking for being My Files/ProgrammingFiles/Programming/flower.zip/train/rose]

The desired file is flower.zip.

I am trying this code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import random

figure, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(10, 5))
for i, a in enumerate(ax.flat):
    files = random.choices(os.listdir("Files/My Files/ProgrammingFiles/Programming/flower.zip/train/rose"), k=3)
    files = [path+file for file in files]
    a.imshow(plt.imread(files[i]))
```

I expected it to plot three images from the desired folder, but instead produced this: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Files/My Files/ProgrammingFiles/Programming/flower.zip/train/rose'

Comment: Did you launch that python program from the Linux terminal?

Comment: I did not, I'm using Google Colab.

Comment: Google Colab cannot access the local machine's file system.

Comment: Is there a way I can get a specific file? Also, how does one launch from the Linux terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Set up Linux on your Chromebook.](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/9145439?hl=en)

Execute the following command in the Linux terminal.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install python3-pip -y
python3 -m pip install -U pip
python3 -m pip install matplotlib
sudo apt install python3-tk -y
```

Run the program.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was unable to set my Chromebook to developer mode (I believe it is too old or outdated to do that), but I figured out that I could just manually upload files to Colab, even if it does take a while. For everyone who wanted an answer to this question, click the folder symbol on the left margin, then click the paper with the up arrow.